# What do these icons mean, next to the HP/Stamina bars?

Tags: bloodborne

I just got icon #. 2 - what is this? It looks like a chest x-ray with an up arrow.

Icon #. 1 I've always had, but it changes from black to yellow - what does this mean?

<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Icon (1) on your picture indicates what mode your melee weapon uses. By default it's empty, when you transform your weapon (L1 on PS4) indicator fills up.

(2) shows the buffs you have from gemstones inserted in your weapons. The one you have on the picture is health regen, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! :) Both are completely correct, I did fortify a Health Regen stone. I wonder what other buffs there are...